# Validar Senha informada em um servidor LDAP

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma página em HTML, CSS bootstrap, js e afins.
A pagina é um self-service para que usuários possam alterar a sua senha.
funciona assim:

```
DIGITE SEU USUÁRIO       :
DIGITE SUA SENHA ATUAL   :
DIGITE SUA NOVA SENHA    :
CONFIRME A NOVA SENHA    :
```

Um formulário simples, minha duvida é a seguinte.
Como validar se a senha atual esta correta, e fazer o tratamento das opções?
A senha atual informada esta errada, tente novamente,
caso tudo foi corretamente, informe senha alterada com sucesso.

Comment: Poderia explicar o que seria esse "afins"? Em que linguagem está programando? Já consegue fazer a comunicação com o LDAP? Se sim, como está fazendo isso? Adicione essas informações para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Comment: Olá Randrade, na verdade eu não possuo isso feito, quando mencionei as tecnologias, na verdade quiz dizer que tenho isso disponível para trazer o resultado final, que pode ser da forma mais simples possivel. Tenho um ideia de como conectar no ldap e imagino que não será problema, mas pensando adiante fiquei na duvida sobre como validar a senha atual que o usuário informar.... e claro, fazer o tratamento do resultado.

Comment: Que tal colocar seu código pra analisarmos o que você já fez e lhe ajudar.

Comment: Eu irei desenvolve-lo e quando chegar na parte que tenho duvida coloco aqui para todos verem.